# Форматирование внутри блока кода

Tags: поддержка, форматирование, редактор

Попался [ответ](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/314322/4928642), в котором есть строка кода с выделением жирным внутри. Как это сделано?

PS: На нажатие Edit для просмотра разметки рейтинга не хватает :(

Comment: Вместо edit можно нажать на "edited 1h ago" и просмотреть исходник - для этого репутация не нужна.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Там html теги `<pre>` и `</b>`:

```
/questions/7868217/swapping-keys-and-values-of-a-map-in-c/34154476#34154476
```

Как-то так: `<pre>/questions/7868217/swapping-keys-and-values-of-a-map-in-c/<b>34154476</b>#<b>34154476</b></pre>`

Comment: Хм.. Я какое-то время назад пытался что-то такое сделать, но не вышло. Странно...