# Изменить цвет кода в ответе, чтобы было видно разницу

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

Сегодня днем я ответил на вопрос, и в комментариях человек, который задал вопрос, спрашивает, что я изменил. А еще и Grundy посоветовал, чтобы я сразу в ответе писал что изменил и как... Согласен, не все могут читать чужой код и сразу ориентироваться. Так вот, возникло предложение в виде вопроса.

Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы когда копируешь вопрос, чтобы на него ответить, выбрать текст другого цвета, чтобы была видна разница между оригиналом и тем куском кода, что ты изменил?

Дополнение к моему предложению.  Ну вот на пример, наш новенький коллега,  начинает писать вопрос и при написании, он видит подобный вопрос. Система же при написании вопроса предлагает возможные похожие варианты  вопроса...  И кликает по возможному похожему вопросу, если в ответе будут видны изменения, на мой взгляд, это удобно...

Comment: Ну и что в вопросе не так?)))))

Comment: Вы наверное знаете, что минусы-плюсы на мете используются больше для голосования "я считаю, что это хорошее предложение" или "я думаю, что это не нужно". Поэтому тут ничего личного, просто кто-то считает, что это не нужно.

Comment: Ага, ничего личного, как в фильмах про чикагских гангстеров, ничего личного братан и выстрел в голову)))))))))))))))))

Comment: Суть в том, что раз эта база знаний, то, по-моему мнению, ответ с кодом надо бы сопровождать комментариями, чтобы дать понимание того, что именно было не так у автора и что именно решает проблему текущий код. В ином случае ни автор, ни другие не будут учиться, а будут развивать умение копипасты, из-за которого итак в сети уже много шутеек по поводу SO. И суть не в том, чтоб прокомментировать каждый расходящийся символ с оригиналом, а в том, чтобы дать знание, на которое как раз и рассчитан ресурс

Comment: В связи с этим  ваше предложение не имеет смысла как такового

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ищейки будут всегда, вопрос в том, чтобы было удобно ориентироваться в коде и изменениях.   И кстати, ищейки свой код не пишут а задают вопросы без когда, чтобы другие за них сделали...

Comment: @Air ну давай еще поразмышляем. Каким образом должен происходить разбор и сопоставление кода? автоматически или вручную? и какого именно кода  (js, java, php, c++ и т.д.)? А если в вопросе не один блок? Если там классы? А если в ответе не один вариант, исправленный авторский, а еще есть варианты? А если в ответе указаны лишь ключевые строки с ошибками? Что с чем должно сопоставляться? В какой момент?

Comment: В ручную, конечно.  Ну вот на примет, нажал я на кнопку "скоприровать код в ответ" и что бы была возможность писать код человеку котовый отвечает другим цветом

Comment: просто одна кнопка, нажав на которую  меняется цвет набираемого текста...  и сразу видно будет что в коде изменилось

Comment: Соглашусь, что нужно писать пояснения, в дополнение к ним можно выделять изменённую часть жирным: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2290/227016

Comment: @mymedia недавно был такой же вопрос, но с более подробными объяснениями, в идеале бы его найти, но у меня не получилось

Comment: когда писал вопрос, ничего подобного мне не выкинуло, я не видел, если честно...

Answer (score 4):

Не стоит приводить в ответе 99% кода, имеющегося в вопросе, достаточно указать требующие изменения строки, добавив словесное описание почему именно так. В таком случае никакого специального выделения внутри кода не требуется. Если же строк, требующих исправления так много, что их количество соизмеримо с первичным кодом в вопросе, то такой вопрос, скорее всего, слишком общий (затрагивает много проблем) и должен быть закрыт для дальнейшей правки и выделения одной конкретной проблемы.

Comment: Согласен. но бывают, разные случаи...  бывает, что надо...

Comment: @Air есть конкретные примеры? Дайте ссылку.

Comment: Вот последний мой ответ на вопрос, благодаря которому и возникла у меня идея. Человек спрашивает, что я изменил... https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/730221/Как-сделать-одинаковые-отступы-с-двух-сторон-на-флексах/730223#730223

Comment: @Air уверен, что здесь не стоило приводить повторно эту простыню кода. В таком виде ответ полезен только автору вопроса, и то если ему хочется сделать полный копипаст. Надо описать **суть** сделанных изменений и привести только лишь их.

Comment: Я сейчас не буду спорить и ковыряться, в каком то вопросе, был случай,  в ответе  были только изменения и новичок  спрашивает - "куда вставить?" . я лично ориентируюсь по статусу человека, если новичок,  в ответе пишу полный ответ

Comment: @Air если возникает вопрос "куда вставить?", значит ответ недостаточно понятен, либо вопрошающий из разряда "дайте мне готовый код, я на контрольной сижу, думать некогда". В первом случае надо править ответ, во втором — закрывать вопрос. А анализировать повторно 99% того же текста в ответе, что уже был в вопросе для поиска исправленного участка, ну уж нет. Эта лишняя трата времени, которую SO как раз ставит своей целью сократить при поиске ответа на поставленный вопрос. Более того, код вопроса должен быть в формате [mcve], и в этом случае    портянки в ответе неоткуда было бы взяться.

Answer (score 1):

Цветом выделять правки в коде не стоит - у нас применяется цветная подсветка синтаксиса, и будет не ясно, где изменения цвета зависят от окружающих символов, а где от воли автора. Вместо выделения цветом лучше использовать жирный или курсивный шрифт. Это возможно, но для этого нужно записать код в HTML.

Пример:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)  // обязательно должно быть возвращаемое значение целого типа
{
    printf("hello, world\n");  // используйте перевод строки, чтобы
                               // не сползало приглашение оболочки
    return 0;
}
```

<sup>[код этого сообщения](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/2261d857-5d2b-48e3-ada7-9afcf6ad8e56/view-source)</sup>

Comment: при желании можно придумать чего-нибудь... например, изменить цвет фона